# Wrapping long numerator

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fractions, mathtools

I have a long square root equation that walks off the edge of the page. See the following picture where the end of the equation is cutoff.

```
\[
S=\sqrt{\frac{306.250+240.250+156.250+110.250+90.250+56.250+30.250+30.250+30.250+56.250+132.250+156.250+380.250+756.250}{14-1}}
\]
```

[image: Square root that is cutoff]

I would like to collapse it so that all of the values can be visible. I understand I can decrease the font size, or mathematically decrease the size of the square root, but I would like a solution that keeps the same font size, and keeps all of the values together under the square root.

How can I move half of the values to the next line so that they remain under the square root? See the following illustration as an example.

```
 --------------------
 | x + x + x + x + ...
 | x + x + x + x + x
 | ------------------
\|         y
```

I've tried the obvious `\newline`, however, it does not pair well with `\sqrt`. The following is the result of that.

[image: Square root with new line]

I am a LaTeX newbie. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is it `splitfrac`/`splitdfrac` from [mathtools](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) you look for?

Comment: @mickep Yep. Appreciate the answer

Comment: @Jaan Try to think to your future readers... I am not sure that the output wanted is the better one to understand your formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @mickep has already suggested in a comment, the `\splitfrac` and `\splitdfrac` macros (provided by the `mathtools` package, a superset of the `amsmath` package) are your friends. The `d` in `\splitdfrac` indicates that its arguments will be processed in display-style math mode.

As the following example code shows, one can split a long numerator (or denominator) term into 3 or more parts by nesting the macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \splitfrac and \splitdfrac macros

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
S&=\sqrt{\frac{%
   \splitfrac{306.250+240.250+156.250+110.250+90.250+56.250+30.250}%
             {+30.250+30.250+56.250+132.250+156.250+380.250+756.250}}%
             {14-1}}\\
 &=\sqrt{\frac{%
   \splitdfrac{\splitdfrac{306.250+240.250+156.250+110.250+90.250}%
                          {+56.250+30.250+30.250+30.250+56.250}}%
                          {+132.250+156.250+380.250+756.250}}%
             {14-1}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\splitdfrac` also increases the vertical separation.  So the choice between two and three lines isn't quite so simple.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for this addition.